# What is ROC curve based on for SVM?

Tags: logistic-regression, svm, auc, roc

I was studying about the ROC curves for Logistic regression. There is a threshold in this method that determines the classification. By changing this threshold we get different confusion matrices and different Sensitivity rates and False Positive rates. Based on them we can draw the ROC curve.

My question is, when we use SVM, what do we draw the ROC curve based on?

Comment: When using an SVM it works exactly the same as it does for logistic regression. SVM's can also output classification probabilities (see for example [the `scikit-learn` API](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.predict_proba)) which can be compared with the threshold to draw the ROC curve.

Comment: @Oxbowerce Thanks. Would you please explain more about how I can draw the ROC curve for an SVM? I didn't understand how to use the probability for that.

Comment: You can use the exact same methodology as you would using the predictions generated by any other model such as a logistic regression. The `scikit-learn` documentation has [an example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.RocCurveDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.RocCurveDisplay.from_estimator) on how to draw the ROC curve, which coincidentally uses an SVM.

Comment: @Oxbowerce Actually I'm trying to implement the methods from an article. There they evaluate the methods with 5-Fold Cross Validation and for each model, they drew a single ROC curve. I saw the example you sent but yet I don't know how to apply cross validation and draw a single ROC curve